# setting breakpoints in gdb-many-window no visual cursor

Tags: emacs, gdb, cursor

I'm using emacs to single step a assembly executable, but i have a odd problem.
in gdb when i use "break main" it give's me the message

> "Breakpoint at 0xDDDDDD"

but no visual cursor, when i look at my breakpoints list i see in the "What" column the message "main". But when i use

> "break main.asm:55"

i see the visual cursor.

compile process:

> nasm -g -f elf -l main.lst main.asm
>
> gcc -g -m32 -o main main.o

ive also tried to use "file program_name" in gdb. Same result.
How can i fix this that when i typ break main i can see the visual cursor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using an older version of nasm

```
>nasm --version
>NASM version 2.07 compiled on Nov  5 2009
```